# How to get google search results with spesific date in Java?

Tags: java, ajax, search, gson

I have a problem to get the results in google search with java programming.
I already used code with Gson, but it just give me 4 results and i can't search it with specific date i want.
I want to get 10 results like URL, Title and content in the first page in search and with spesific date like from 1 january 2013 until 30 january 2013.
In the manual search in google we can use this spesific date when searching, but i don't know how to use it in Java.
The code i used:

```
String google = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=9&q=";
String search = "news";
String charset = "UTF-8";
URL url = new URL(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset));
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);

..............................................
```

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

use Jsoup api best for html parsing

[Using JSoup to scrape Google Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708049/using-jsoup-to-scrape-google-results)

Comment: Thx for the answer. But i still can't search with spesific date. Can you help me?