# how to parse google result number by java

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I want to get google result count by parsing google html in java,how can I get it? I used Jsoup library,but I just could parse links,not result count
[image: getting the result count:23,600]

Comment: Possible Duplicate Of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708049/using-jsoup-to-scrape-google-resultso

Comment: I need result count ,not links and their title

Answer (score 0):

String divs = doc.getElementById("resultStats").childNode(0).toString();