# Unable to correctly return links for google search result

Tags: java, jsoup, scraper

Hi my code is unable to return links that are listed in the search result for Google, I can't seem to find the solution. It seems that it only views the homepage of the Google but I already added the link on a search result. See my code below:

```
public class jsoupScraper {

 public static void main (String args[]) {

        Document doc;
        try{
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com.ph/?gfe_rd=cr ei=yaXVV4CAGION2AT9q5OICQ#q=Silence+of+the+lambs")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla").ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(0).get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a");
            int count = 0;
            for (Element link : links) {

            if(count < 10) {
                System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
                count++;
            } else
                break;

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Actually I just copied this on this link: [Using JSoup to scrape Google Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708049/using-jsoup-to-scrape-google-results) and I just did a minor modification but it still doesn't output correctly. When I tried to run the original code it will just terminate with no result.

Here is a sample output

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww
https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi
https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8
https://www.youtube.com/?gl=PH&tab=w1
https://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn
https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo
https://www.google.com/intl/en/options/
https://www.google.com/calendar?tab=wc
```

Thank you for the help in advance, and it seems to be the same case with HTMLUnit

Comment: The code is perfect and its working for me. How did you run the code?

Comment: i can verify that the code works

Comment: I run it as Java in Eclipse